# Does this phrase at the beginning of the sentence need the comma?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, commas

> In production, these files should already exist.

I was trying to explain to a non-native English speaker that this sentence needed the comma after `production`, but when trying to explain the grammar as to why, I realized it was only a feeling I had. When I looked it up, I found [this link](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000074.htm), which says if a prepositional phrase is less than four words at the beginning, then it does not need a comma.

So, just to clarify, does this need a comma? And what is the reasoning behind the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a different explanation. The natural order of the phrase is **"These files should already exist in production"**. So if you take **"in production"** and place it in the beggining of the phrase, you should use a comma.

Comment: Perfect! That was my initial explanation, but I figured there might be a rule I could link him to. My initial response was:
 I don't know the name of the rule, but because it can also go at the end of the sentence without changing its structure I believe:
These files should already exist in production.

Comment: I'll try to find it and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @NightHallow You won't find any "rules" where the comma is concerned. There are guidelines, though, and except for the quagmire of the Oxford comma, they're all reliable. Here's the **[APA](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/when-use-comma.aspx)** version.